# How to erase job via gitlab api

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, jobs, erase, gitlab-api

I have an issue were I am the owner of a project on a gitlab server, and I can successfully delete all artifacts for a job as listed in the docs..

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" "https://gitlab.corp.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/1/artifacts"
```

and I get a 204, meaning it has successfully deleted them.

But , when I try to do the similar command to delete the job. I get a 403 forbidden error...

```
curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <token>" "https://gitlab.corp.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/1/erase"
```

This is the offical documentation, I am using. I am a gitlab admin and project owner. So, it can't be a permission thing, so it is something else...

Can someone tell me what I am missing? I am the owner, why can't I delete the bloody thing?

Comment: Q: "Can someone tell me what I am missing" A: some example of what you did/ code/ anything for us to go on

Comment: What other setting do you need? I am not sure what to provide?

Comment: After a bit of research, you can't delete an archived job. So, change the arcive settings to a high value and you can clean the jobs....

Comment: If that answers your question you should put is as an answer. Then wait a few days and mark it as such. This will help other users as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found one solution [here](https://gist.github.com/carceneaux/b75d483e3e0cb798ae60c424300d5a0b).

Full code next:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Written by Chris Arceneaux
# GitHub: https://github.com/carceneaux
# Email: carcenea@gmail.com
# Website: http://arsano.ninja
#
# Note: This code is a stop-gap to erase Job Artifacts for a project. I HIGHLY recommend you leverage
#       "artifacts:expire_in" in your .gitlab-ci.yml
#
# https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifactsexpire_in
#
# Software Requirements: curl, jq
#
# This code has been released under the terms of the Apache-2.0 license
# http://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0


# project_id, find it here: https://gitlab.com/[organization name]/[repository name] at the top underneath repository name
project_id="207"

# token, find it here: https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens
token="TODO_ADD_YOUR_TOKEN"
server="gitlab.com"

# Retrieving Jobs list page count
total_pages=$(curl -sD - -o /dev/null -X GET \
  "https://$server/api/v4/projects/$project_id/jobs?per_page=100" \
  -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${token}" | grep -Fi X-Total-Pages | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')

# Creating list of Job IDs for the Project specified with Artifacts
job_ids=()
echo ""
echo "Creating list of all Jobs that currently have Artifacts..."
echo "Total Pages: ${total_pages}"
for ((i=2;i<=${total_pages};i++)) #starting with page 2 skipping most recent 100 Jobs
do
  echo "Processing Page: ${i}/${total_pages}"
  response=$(curl -s -X GET \
    "https://$server/api/v4/projects/$project_id/jobs?per_page=100&page=${i}" \
    -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: ${token}")
  length=$(echo $response | jq '. | length')
  for ((j=0;j<${length};j++))
  do
    if [[ $(echo $response | jq ".[${j}].artifacts_file | length") > 0 ]]; then
        echo "Job found: $(echo $response | jq ".[${j}].id")"
        job_ids+=($(echo $response | jq ".[${j}].id"))
    fi
  done
done

# Loop through each Job erasing the Artifact(s)
echo ""
echo "${#job_ids[@]} Jobs found. Commencing removal of Artifacts..."
for job_id in ${job_ids[@]};
do
  response=$(curl -s -X DELETE \
    -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${token}" \
    "https://$server/api/v4/projects/$project_id/jobs/$job_id/artifacts")
  echo "Processing Job ID: ${job_id} - Status: $(echo $response | jq '.status')"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Find out that pipeline with all jobs can be deleted. Maybe because there is several jobs inside.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `X-Total-Pages` header is now missing in big projects (for performance reasons). Fortunately when a page number is too high, an empty json list (`[]`) is returned so it is quite easy to use a loop such as (here in bash):

```bash
PER_PAGE=100
PAGE=1
while JOBS=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $TOKEN" "$GITLAB_INSTANCE/$PROJECT_ID/jobs?per_page=$PER_PAGE&page=$PAGE&sort=asc") && [ "$JOBS" != "[]" ]
do
   for JOB in $(echo $JOBS | jq .[].id)
   do
      [...]
   done
   PAGE=$((PAGE+1))
done
```